# xtext formatter questions, including linewraping, keywords replacing

Tags: xtext

I have few questions about formatter of xtext. I'm dealing with a SQL-like language.

- I'm using three default setLinewrap() commands for comments. However it will insert a space after `SL_COMMENT`,

like

```
UPDATE plays SET scores = scores - [ 12, 21 ] WHERE id = '123-afde'; // removes all occurences of 12 and 21 from scores

SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE t = now();
```

become

```
UPDATE plays SET scores = scores - [ 12, 21 ] WHERE id = '123-afde';
// removes all occurences of 12 and 21 from scores
 SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE t = now ( );
```

could I remove that extra space?

- How to wrap at specific place **only if line is too long**? I tried `setLinewrap(0, 1, 1)` but doesn't work.

For example

```
UPDATE table SET a = a + 1 WHERE a > 0;

UPDATE tablelongna SET c = c + 1 WHERE c IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 7, 8);
```

become

```
UPDATE table SET a = a + 1 WHERE a > 0;

UPDATE tablelongna SET c = c + 1 
WHERE c IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 7, 8);
```

- I use `setLinewrap(2).after(T_SEMICOLON);` and it works fine for usual case. However for batch query

like this

```
BEGIN BATCH
    UPDATE ......;

    UPDATE ......;

APPLY BATCH;

NEXT QUERY.....
```

I try to use `setLinewrap(1).before(K_APPLY);` to overwrite it but it doesn't work. Can't use `setNoSpace()` or `setNoLinewrap()` otherwise `APPLY BATCH` will not have it's own line.

- Can I replace all keyword to upper case in formatter? ex. `select * from foo;` to `SELECT * FROM foo;`. It looks like all APIs can only manipulating whitespaces/newlines?
- Not sure it's my problem or not, I can't hot swap formatter in debug mode. Such that I have to quit another Eclipse instance and run again to see change.